# Существует ли процесс (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно реализовать проверку на существование процессов с определенными заголовками окон, если хоть у одного процесса заголовок окна совпадает со списком, то выполняется действие.

Comment: Вопрос задан как-то, скажем мягко, не очень понятно... Если это то, о чем я думаю, то - `EnumWindows` + `GetWindowsText`, например.

Comment: @Harry да, именно с помощью этого, хотелось бы пример реализации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, раз правильно понял :), то что-то вроде (не компилировал - это набросок для понимания) вызова

```
EnumWindows(CheckProg,LPARAM(searched_title));
```

`searched_title` - искомое название окна, а `CheckProg` - функция обратного вызова вроде

```
BOOL CALLBACK CheckProg(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char * searched_title = (char*)lParam;
    char txt[256];
    // Можно проверить на видимость окна, например...
    ULONG style = GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_STYLE);
    if (style & WS_VISIBLE == 0) return TRUE;
    // Получаем строку заголовка
    if (GetWindowText(hwnd,txt,256))
    {
        // Совпадение. Выполняем, что надо
        ....
        return FALSE;  // Все, дальшейшее перечисление в EnumWindows не нужно
    }
    return TRUE;  // Чтоб EnumWindows работал дальше
}
```

Примерно так...

**Update**

Вот код, перечисляющий все - видимые, невидимые - окна. Компилировал VC++2017 без замечаний. Работает. Скорее всего у вас проблемы или в неверном названии окна, или в использовании Unicode (если работаете с ним).

См. также http://rextester.com/IGMOUX1928

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"user32")

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK CheckProg(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char * searched_title = (char*)lParam;
    char txt[256];
    if (GetWindowText(hwnd,txt,256))
    {
        cout << "Found title [" << txt << "]\n";
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    EnumWindows(CheckProg,LPARAM("test.exe"));
}
```

Comment: Пробовал править, все ошибки исправил, но код не работает

Comment: См. дополненный ответ. Это реально работающий код.

Comment: Он никак не хочет принимать txt в GetWindowText

Comment: Приведенный код скомпилировался? Что получается? Допишите к `GetWindowText` в ветви `else` вызов `GetLastError` - что он говорит?

Comment: В том то и проблема, что он не хочет компилироваться, пишет, что Char * несовместим с LPWSTR, попробовал написать так: `mbstowcs(wtext, txt, strlen(txt) + 1);` и в if вместо txt написал wtext

Comment: Ну так используйте соответствующие функции для широких строк; я написал для ASCII. Соответственно, и проверки на совпадение должны быть иными.